# How to choose between join(broadcast) and collect with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark 2.2.1.

I have a small DataFrame (less than 1M) and I have a computation on a big DataFrame that will need this small one to compute a column in an UDF.

What is the best option regarding performance

Is it better to broadcast this DF (I don't know if Spark will do the cartesian into memory).

```
bigDF.crossJoin(broadcast(smallDF))
     .withColumn(udf("$colFromSmall", $"colFromBig"))
```

or to collect it and use the `small` value directly in the udf

```
val small = smallDF.collect()
bigDF.withColumn(udf($"colFromBig"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Both will `collect` data first, so in terms of memory footprint there is no difference. So the choice should be dictated by the logic:

- If you can do better than default execution plan and don't want to create your own, `udf` might be a better approach.
- If it is just a Cartesian, and requires subsequent `explode` - perish the though - just go with the former option.

As suggested [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48583582/how-to-choose-between-joinbroadcast-and-collect-with-spark/48587009?noredirect=1#comment84186080_48587009) by [T.Gawęda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5811800/t-gaw%c4%99da) in the second case you can use broadcast

```
val small = spark.spark.broadcast(smallDF.collect())
bigDF.withColumn(udf($"colFromBig"))
```

It might provide some performance improvements if `udf` is reused.

Comment: Cross Join will make a copy or rows fronm smallDF for each row in the first DF. Memory footprint will be higher, I got a lot of OOM before I switched to second approach. Of course manual broadcast is better only if it's necessary in UDF

Comment: Btw. Please suggest manual broadcast instead of direct reference :)

Comment: @T.Gawęda I would focus on explicit arguments, I am not sure if broadcast is beneficial here, but done :)